How to disable verification peer in Django
In localhost my configuration works fine but in production i recieve a "Connection unexpectedly closed" error
This is my configuration...
 EMAIL_HOST='xxxxxxx'
 EMAIL_PORT=25
 EMAIL_HOST_USER='xxxxxxx'
 EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='xxxxxxx'
 DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL=EMAIL_HOST_USER 
 EMAIL_BACKEND='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'


Welcome to SO!  Some additional context would be helpful.  From the title and the tags I'm guessing you are attempting to send an email from a Django application, is that right?  What host are you using to send the mail?  Are you able to successfully send an email from that host outside of Django?  Sounds a bit like a network/firewall issue.

yes, that is correct, but with others project in php with laravel that function works fine, with the same conditions, same server, same permission, same all, the only difference is python with django, thats the reasson beacasue i suspect that i am missing something. With laravel i must disable an option called verify_peer and its work fine.
